# How should I format a date

Tags: java, date

I'm writing a project on travel company in blueJ and I have some problems with dates. The aim of a project is to develop a simplified system for the management of vacation packages available in a travel agency. The simple products can be related to flights, hotel booking, car rental or activities. Each product includes start and end dates ad I don't know how to write a date(what format) when I'm creating a product. How can I do this?

What should I change to write the date (when creating a product) for example in a format:"dd/MM/yyyy"?
This is the creation of one of a products:

```
public boolean createProductHotel(String ID, String name, String city, double price,Date start, Date end, int number, int stars)
{
    Hotel hotel = new Hotel(ID, name, city, price, start, end, number, stars);
    for (Product product : Products.values())
    {
        if (hotel.getID().equals(product.getID()))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    Products.put(hotel.getID(),hotel);   
    return true;
}
```

Comment: A format is not the same thing as the concept behind the entity. Any given Date could be formatted various ways, and doing so should be reserved as a UI function. Similar for any given floating point number.

Comment: What does that source code have to do with writing a date in a format?

Answer (score 0):

A Java `Date` object simply stores the UTC time of the date it represents. They are formatted when they are displayed as a UI function, and one `Date` can be displayed in a number of formats  during execution. You don't need to format dates when they are stored as instance data.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to worry about Date while storing. It is required only in the case of displaying date. Following codes will help you

```
  try {
        String dateString = "20-05-1999 03:05:20";
        SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm");
        Date startDate = simpledateformat.parse(dateString);
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(startDate);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6);
        Date endDate=cal.getTime();            
        System.out.println("End date is = "+outputDateFormat.format(endDate));

    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.out.println("Parse exception");
    }
```

in the above code i'm creating `Date` from one string and adding 6 days to that date and then displaying in another format